# Show the key presses of shortcuts on Linux

Tags: linux, video, keyboard-shortcuts, presentations

I'm about to hold a course for learning Linux. I'd like the participants to see what keys and key combinations I press. Is there anything like [Mouseposé](http://boinx.com/mousepose/overview/) for Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used key-mon and I'm really impressed with it. It does exactly what you want without eing a nuisance. The only let down, is that if you keep holding any of the modifiers down, e.g. control, then the consecutive key combinations (ctrl + x, then ctrl + s) will not display the control key as being pressed down.

For running e.g. a tutorial on Emacs navigation, this somewhat of a let down. Apart from that, I find key-mon great.

Answer (score 1):

[Key-mon](http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/) is a little python program I found recently that seems to do exactly what you want. I have not tried it myself yet, so I can't comment on how well it works.

Answer (score 1):

[screenkey](https://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/screenkey/) is "a screencast tool to display your keys". It allows a fair amount of customization and has worked really well for me personally. It does not have the same issue as key-mon when it comes to sequential combination including modifiers, instead it correctly displays the modifier that is being held down with each subsequent key press.

Example animation from the application's website:
[image]